# Upload Image on click of image

Tags: angularjs

I want to upload images on click of img tag.When user Click on image, file input tag will call and user chose any image and set this image to clicked img tag.

How i will achive.Can anyone tell me.

Comment: Can you show some effort? Does it have to be actually uploaded or just visible for the user?

Comment: @putvande Uploaded and selected image also get display on position of clicked img.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by triggering a click event with jquery. First thing to do is.

1. Create An image tag (I'm assuming you want to put a no picture image on this tag)
2. Create a file input tag somewhere on the page, preferable under the above image tag.
3. Hide the file input (Set display to none with css);
4. use jquery to trigger a click on the file input from the click handler of the "no picture" image.
5. handle your upload as usual using your file input tag.

also get [this](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) angular module that makes file upload easy in angular

The HTML

`<img src="no_image.png" ng-click="triggerUpload()" class="image-holder"/>
 <input type="file" ng-file-select="uploadImage($files)" style="display:none" id="fileInput" name="filedata"/>`

now to trigger the hidden file input control

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
$scope.triggerUpload=function()
{
 var fileuploader = angular.element("#fileInput");
    fileuploader.on('click',function(){
        console.log("File upload triggered programatically");
    })
    fileuploader.trigger('click')
}

$scope.uploadImage=function(selectedfiles)
{
    $upload.upload({
       url:"link to server script",
       file:selectedFiles
    })
}
```

See [this](http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) for a demo of the module

Comment: i was used above code but this code was not work.Problem is that when i click on image then file chooser will not open.and @Shanks in your demo link.file input tag get display.i want to display only one image.and when i click on that image.file input tag is open. so user select any image and then selected image get display on clicked image. Don't display file input tag to user.

Comment: Hi..sorry my bad...i forgot to add an event handler on the image tag. I have updated the code.

Comment: here is a fiddle for the above code working. http://jsfiddle.net/JohnyCockblocker/VYXpM/3/

Comment: I am using Bootstrap model(PopUp).In that model i am try to  access  this code. file chooser is also get opened.but Problem is that   selected image was not display at clicked position.even if uploadImage function also not called.can you tell me why problem this occur?

Comment: also your jsFiddle example was not working correctly.In your example File chooser is also get opened.but Problem is that selected image was not display at clicked position.

Comment: can you fiddle you code? i really dont understand what you want. My fiddle just shows you how to display the file chooser by clicking an image tag which i assume is the major reason for this question.

Comment: your Fiddle example was right. and i want same as u provide.also i want to user select any images from file chooser.after press OK, selected image get display on clicked image(clicked image is first where we click to open file chooser)

Comment: Did u Understand what I want

Comment: I need to see some effort from your end

Answer (score 1):

You can try ng-file-upload https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

1. Create img tag
2. Use directive straight in img tag

Answer (score 1):

@shanks solution doesn't address setting the image to the clicked image. I have modified the code to address the same.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="uploadImage($files)" id="file-input" name="filedata"/> 
<img src="no_image.png" ng-click="triggerUpload()" id="imageId"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

In browsers supporting the File API, you can use the FileReader constructor to read files once they have been selected by the user. Supported browsers - IE 10+, Safari 6.0.2+, Chrome 7+, Firefox 3.6+, Opera 12.02+.

```
$scope.triggerUpload=function() {
    var fileuploader = angular.element("#file-input");
    fileuploader.on('click',function(){
        console.log("File upload triggered programatically");
    });
    fileuploader.on('change', function(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('imageId').src = reader.result;
        }

        var files = fileuploader[0].files;
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

    });
    fileuploader.trigger('click')
}
```

Uploading code is same as @shanks solution

```
$scope.uploadImage=function(selectedfiles)
{
    $upload.upload({
       url:"link to server script",
       file:selectedFiles
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<img url="#Your image url" alt="click here to add file upload" />
<div id="fileUpload" />
```

and script

```
$('img').click(function () {
AddFileUpload();
 });

function AddFileUpload() {
    $('#fileUpload').append('<input type="file"/>');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/25xGQ/1/)